# htaccess disabling require valid-user triggers 500 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a development website in use before deploying to live.
The development website has a password with .htaccess and .htpasswd. The password login works fine.

For a particular functionality related to an external server having to access a page on the server, I got to disable the password temporarily for testing.
Normally this gets done by commenting out the "Require valid-user" line. For some strange reason, I get a 500 error if I comment out that line. This used to work fine in the past.

With password:

```
AuthType basic
AuthName "***"
Require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/usr/***/.htpasswd"
```

With password disabled:

```
AuthType basic
AuthName "***"
#Require valid-user
AuthUserFile "/usr/***/.htpasswd"
```

The # is the only difference. I also made sure that the file is not in UTF-8-BOM encoding, but stays in UTF-8 encoding. UTF-8-BOM also causes a 500 error.
Any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: Try to check your `.htaccess` file at http://www.htaccesscheck.com/

Comment: I tried that, as expected, the syntax was fine, but the reality is a 500 error when I comment out that one line. As mentioned, I have done this before several times to be exact. Why this suddenly happens is very odd. Commenting out the entire section works, but for timing reasons, I do not always want to comment out the whole lot and then possibly miss one.

Comment: Check error log of Apache server, `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: No luck with that since I do not have access to the server logs files. They are at the hosting company.